Freemarker, formatting date issue
The string is this one:
2024-05-08T09:55:57Z

And with this:
content?matches('[0-9]{4}-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]T[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]([+-][0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]d|Z)')

content?datetime?string['dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm']

I have:
Unparseable date: "2024-05-08T09:52:55Z"

I can't understand what I am doing wrong.
BTW, with  '\d' and '\\d' I had an error
freemarker parseException error: encountered "d" (100), after "\"/\\".


The actual error message (from which you apparently only show the last line) is something like this:

The string doesn't match the expected date/time/date-time format. The
string to parse was: "2024-05-08T09:55:57Z". The expected format was:
"MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a". The nested reason given follows: Unparseable
date: "2024-05-08T09:55:57Z"

So, you haven't set the datetime_format setting to match the parsed date. Either set it to iso, or use ?datetime.iso.
See also: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_setting.html#topic.dateTimeFormatSettings
